# Change package name of java and aidl files

Tags: android, package, rename, aidl, android-framework

Basically I have lots of files in some packages, I want to add some other text in package name, But in the same time i want all the files should also change their package names and import statement automatically for both **JAVA** and **AIDL** files, as files number are too many and it is going to take lots of time if i do it manually. Please let me know if there is any way doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use any IDE? They usually have tools for such refactoring.

Comment: yes, Eclipse, I got that now, it just skipped from my mind. But it seems renaming is not working for aidl files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

Right click on the package name -> **Refactor** -> **Rename** or (`shift + alt + r`) or (`F2`) after selecting package.

Decide which one you want to rename and it should, hopefully, update for the entire project.

Make sure to do a backup first :)

**Edit:**

It can easily be done with java files, but do not know if `AIDL` files package name can be changed automatically, I did that manually. Ankit

Comment: yeah i know it but it seems not working for aidl files. Thanks anyways